# IBM Mobilefirst V8 - Custom Direct update on hybrid application using Ionic v3.20.0 is not happening

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement customized direct update in ionic v3.20.0 but while accessing to the below code, am unable to proceed. I can't find any way to do it as the below function is not there in worklight.d.ts file,but can be found at worklight.js file.

The plugin used is cordova-plugin-mfp. The solution provided in the official doc is relevant to only cordova application,that can be done through index.js file which has the function WlCommonInit(). As per the doc the below code is to be called from this function, but unable to do this in ionic-cordova based application.

```
wl_DirectUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {
// Implement custom Direct Update logic
```

};

Pleas refer to the below link for further information.
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/

Please help me to implement this in ionic v3.20.0 which need to be implemented in typescript.  Thanks!.

Comment: Is it issue seen on android or iOS  or both ? what is cordova-plugin-mfp version is in use ? what is cordova-android and cordova-ios version ?

Comment: yes. currently working with android platform android 6.4.0.
The cordova plugin version is : cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017121811.

Comment: use latest cordova-android@7.0.0 and cordova-plugin-mfp

Comment: can you share the worklight.d.ts file of the latest cordova-plugin-mfp. since this particular mfp plugin is used in our project we can't upgrade it.Please let me know if we have access to the mentioned code snippet in worklight.d.ts file of  the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Presently there is no typescript API for `wl_DirectUpdateChallengeHandler` in `cordova-plugin-mfp` to customize direct update in Ionic Applications.

However you can do implementation in the JavaScript and include it in the Ionic Project. Following are the steps :

- Create a folder called `js` inside the path `src/assets` of the project
- Create a new JS file with following code and save it as `wldirectudpate.js`

```
function wlCommonInit() {
             console.log(">> wlCommonInit() ..." );  
             wl_DirectUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {
                 // Implement custom Direct Update logic
             };
        };
```

- Add the JS location in index.html file which is located at /src/index.html

`<script src="assets/js/wldirectudpate.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Vittal for the help. just wanted to ask one more thing can we override the default pop up of direct update with ionic based alert controller. but this need to be implemented in ts file. so could you please help me on this.

Comment: The wlCommonInit() function is invoked by window object when window is loaded.I tried to override this by calling it from app.component.ts file by using 
declare var wlCommonInit and using it in constructor by calling wlCommonInit() but unfortunately I got error as unhandled promise rejection and stating wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler is not defined . kindly help me on this as I have tried almost all possible ways.

Comment: @vikaskumar Instead of overriding `wlCommonInit`, Can you try by overriding  `wl_DirectUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate` in the  app.component.ts file ?